# SharePoint host app with ApI

Tags: sharepoint-addin

How can I use Office 365 API with SharePoint hosted app ?

To access Office 365 services like mail,calender and Lync.

Answer (score 4):

You can not use O365 APIs in sharepoint hosted app because right now the only supported project types are:

1. NET Windows Store Apps
2. .NET Windows Store Universal Apps
3. Windows Forms Applications
4. WPF Applications
5. ASP.NET MVC Web Applications
6. ASP.NET Web Forms Applications
7. Xamarin Android and iOS Applications
8. Multi-device Hybrid Apps

Besides that, these APIs are in preview mode. For more info check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605892.aspx)

Comment: In fact, the JS O365 API cannot be called from the browser at the moment. Be it a SharePoint Hosted App or a simple web page. This is because the Office team is still sorting out cross domain related issues. Only way to call it right now is through Office Apps or through .net code.

Comment: Besides that O365 APIs are not supported for SP yet even in provider hosted app. Check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98520/bad-request-in-provider-hosted-app

Comment: True. Check JThake's comments here for the technical reason: http://blogs.office.com/2014/05/12/net-and-javascript-libraries-for-office-365-apis/